# numpy.where , numpy.take and indices on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got 2-d array that looks like this:

```
my_array
array([[6, 1, 4],
       [4, 8, 4],
       [6, 3, 5]])
```

After using `np.where` I've got a tuple with two arrays for both dimensions

```
indices = np.where(my_array > 4)


(array([0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64), 
array([0, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

my question are

1. is there a method to turn these arrays into iterable set of paired indices without iterating through them with a for loop?

   what I would like to get is a list(?) of tuples with pairs of indices that I could directly use over array to get the objects one at a time.

   So in this case

```
    paired_indices = [ (0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2) ]


    my_array[paired_indices[0]]
    6

    my_array[paired_indices[1]]
    8
```

2. How can I use `numpy.take(my_array, indices)` to get the proper elements when the arrays are multidimensional? It works fine on 1-dimensional array, but I couldn't figure so far how to deal with more dimensions.

   when I use:

```
    a = np.take(my_array, indices)
```

the result is:

```
    array([[6, 1, 4, 4],
           [6, 1, 6, 4]])
```

3. how was the result of

```
    a = np.take(my_array, indices)
```

calculated into below, and how could you interpret this result?

```
    array([[6, 1, 4, 4],
           [6, 1, 6, 4]])
```

Comment: "is there a method to turn these arrays into iterable set of paired indices without iterating through them with a for loop?" Why would you not want to iterate over them?

Comment: BTW, I think you are looking for just `my_array[indices]` which is what the result of `np.where` is designed to be used with

Answer (score 0):

```
In [13]: arr = np.array([[6, 1, 4],
    ...:        [4, 8, 4],
    ...:        [6, 3, 5]])
In [14]: idx = np.nonzero(arr>4)
In [15]: idx
Out[15]: (array([0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 2]))
```

This tuple can be used directly to index the array, the result being a 1d array of the >4 values:

```
In [16]: arr[idx]
Out[16]: array([6, 8, 6, 5])
```

it can also  be used to modify values

```
In [17]: arr1 = arr.copy()
In [18]: arr1[idx] = 10
In [19]: arr1
Out[19]: 
array([[10,  1,  4],
       [ 4, 10,  4],
       [10,  3, 10]])
```

You can get an array index pairs with:

```
In [20]: np.argwhere(arr>4)
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

`argwhere` just applies `transpose` to the `where`:

```
In [21]: np.transpose(idx)
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

`arr[idx]` is the equivalent of:

```
In [22]: arr[idx[0],idx[1]]
Out[22]: array([6, 8, 6, 5])
```

`np.take` is a way of indexing along just one axis at at time, so isn't very useful in this context. The indices in `idx` are meant to be used together, not individually.